# Docker Image for creating a windows virt and download files to it

Tags: selenium, docker, vagrant

I want to use docker to download a vagrant windows image and download selenium jars on it and have it bring up a selenium hub. I'm not sure what the best way to do it or even if it is possible. I believe it should be doable to get a vagrant image of windows with docker but I'm not sure about the latter i.e. have the windows image download selenium jars and start up the hub. Does anyone have any ideas to achieve this?

Comment: are you sure you want to run vagrant within the docker container ? usually docker runs on top of vagrant, not the other way. you could have vagrant with docker providers to run your system, then a windows machine with IE and running selenium from the dockers calling remote IE.

Answer (score 0):

Docker (as of its main known implementation in 2015) is based on Linux kernel feature to launch docker containers.

As commented by Frédéric Henri, and detailed in "[Vagrant - Docker provider vs. docker provisioner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30398541/6309)", docker is more rarely used as **provider**, running vagrant machine in docker container, instead of VM/cloud as other providers do.

You can still check "[Using Docker with Vagrant](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/02/10/using-docker-with-vagrant/)" to see a concrete example.

Comment: `would you be able to download and run a Windows Vagrant image on a Linux machine?` yes clear; thats what vagrant is for. you can run windows vagrant image from mac or linux as you would run a windows VM (virtual box/VMWare) from mac or linux. saying that though, I am not clear on the OP process; usually you would run docker on top of vagrant (as the VM provider) but not running vagrant from the docker container, does not make much sense to me

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I agree: I have reworded the answer accordingly.

Comment: So would there be a better way then to do it since it seems it may not be as feasible to do a vagrant image inside a docker container? To clarify I am on a mac which is why I needed the dirt to suit my needs. Wanted to get an automated solution for doing this.

Comment: @user3626708 I don't have any direct solution: maybe explore http://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/02/10/using-docker-with-vagrant/ to see if you can specify a container which will do the download for you.